# What does the suffix 号 mean when it's attached to animal names?

Tags: suffixes

One of the [definitions for the suffix 号 in 大辞林](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8F%B7) looks like this:

> 列車・船・飛行機・動物などの名に付けて用いる。
>   「ひかり―」

I'm somewhat familiar with this suffix from fiction.  For example, I remember it from the anime series ふしぎの海のナディア, which had a submarine called the ノーチラス号.  And I've seen it used for other forms of transportation in fiction, too, like airships, and even a race car.

But I haven't seen it used for animal names, and the definition above says it can attach to the names of 動物 as well.  [Wikipedia's disambiguation page for 号](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%B7) says something similar:

> ウマ、イヌなど、動物の名前につける接尾辞。

But it doesn't say when it would be used, and I can't remember having seen any pet or animal names ending in 号.  So I'm curious: do people still use the suffix this way?  If so, when would it be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~号 appears to be used in cases where the animal's name is formally registered in some way, like with [show dogs](http://www.nihonken-hozonkai.or.jp/page011.html), and also with working animals such as police dogs.  This name may not be the normal name of the animal, just as in English with show dogs that have a registered name and a day to day name ("call name").

The 警察犬 article on Wikipedia gives a link to [this example](http://www.asahi.com/eco/OSK201001180092.html) (linked for the adorableness. There is a photo.)

> 登録名は「クリーク号」、元の名前は「くぅ」

In most of the article he's called 「くぅ」, so that would be the usual name although 「クリーク号」 is the registered name.

I don't think there's a direct translation as there's not anything added onto registered names in English - although as with the example the two names are often related - the call name being a shortening of or reference to the registered name.

Comment: For some reason, Googling is well-received on here but I honestly do not feel that you have a feel for the word in question.  Snailboat, in his/her calibre, could have easily googled in Japanese what you have.  What does 号 imply?  Why do people add it to the names? That kind of stuff is missing.